# Zurb Foundation 5.3 - Off Canvas not working "TypeError: this[method] is undefined"

Tags: javascript, html, css, zurb-foundation

I recently updated a project to Foundation 5.3 and simply cannot get [Off Canvas](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/offcanvas.html) to work. I have tried multiple versions of jQuery as well (1.x - 2.x)

I've even setup a clean [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hnNy5/14/embedded/result/) page to test with all the appropriate code (simplified):

```
<div class="off-canvas-wrap" data-off-canvas>
  <div class="inner-wrap">
    <aside class="right-off-canvas-menu">
        <h1>Hello</h1>
    </aside>

    <a href="#" class="right-off-canvas-toggle">Menu</a>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).foundation();
</script>
```

Confused if I have done something wrong or if there is a bug somewhere?

Oddly enough, manually adding the class `move-left` to the menu causes the CSS transition to slide properly, so it seems to be an issue of the toggle not binding properly.

On load, the console does not mention any errors.

Programmatically calling `$('.off-canvas-wrap').foundation('offcanvas', 'open', 'move-left');` returns `"TypeError: this[method] is undefined"`

Comment: Are you sure that the foundation library is loaded?

Answer (score 3):

Oh man, it's been one of those days... To anyone who is underslept and tearing your hair out, check maybe that you have set the data attribute `data-offcanvas` not `data-off-canvas`.

**Correct:**
`<div class="off-canvas-wrap" data-offcanvas>`

**Wrong:**
`<div class="off-canvas-wrap" data-off-canvas>`

Comment: I was having the same problem, until I realized I forgot the data element altogether.

Comment: Per the spec (shown here on MDN website) you can only have data-* not data-*-*: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes